# core.typed not reporting type error in repl

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.typed

Here is a part of the example taken from core.typed github repo:

```
(ns typedclj.rps-async
  (:require [clojure.core.typed :as t]
            [clojure.core.async :as a]
            [clojure.core.typed.async :as ta]))

(t/defalias Move
  "A legal move in rock-paper-scissors"
  (t/U ':rock ':paper ':scissors))

(t/defalias PlayerName
  "A player's name in rock-paper-scissors"
  t/Str)

(t/defalias PlayerMove
  "A move in rock-paper-scissors. A Tuple of player name and move"
  '[PlayerName Move])

(t/defalias RPSResult
  "The result of a rock-paper-scissors match.
  A 3 place vector of the two player moves, and the winner"
  '[PlayerMove PlayerMove PlayerName])

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Implementation
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(t/ann MOVES (t/Vec Move))
(def MOVES [:rock :paper :scissors])

(t/ann BEATS (t/Map Move Move))
(def BEATS {:rock :scissors, :paper :rock, :scissors :paper})
(def BEATS {:a :b})
```

Note that in the last line I redefined BEATS to {:a :b}, which conflicts its type annotation, but when I eval this in the repl, no error is thrown. I was expecting an error because the latest version of core.typed is said to be able to report type errors at the runtime.

Here is the entire project.clj file:

```
            (defproject typedclj "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
                        :description "FIXME: write description"
                        :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
                        :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
                                  :url  "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
                        :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                                       [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.346.0-17112a-alpha" :exclusions [org.clojure/tools.analyzer.jvm]]
                                       [org.clojure/core.typed "0.2.92"]
                                       [clj-http "1.1.2"]
                                       [http-kit "2.1.18"]
                                       ]
                        :repl-options {:nrepl-middleware [clojure.core.typed.repl/wrap-clj-repl]}
                        :main ^:skip-aot typedclj.core
                        :target-path "target/%s"
                        :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

---

With core.typed 0.3.0-alpha2 this type error is nicely catched:

```
Type Error (/private/var/folders/5d/44ctbbln4dsflgzxph1dm8wr0000gn/T/form-init3488589171262628870.clj:36:12) Type mismatch:

Expected:   typedclj.rps-async/Move

Actual:     (t/Val :b)
in: :b


Type Error (/Users/kaiyin/personal_config_bin_files/workspace/typedclj/src/typedclj/rps_async.clj:36:12) Type mismatch:

Expected:   (t/Map typedclj.rps-async/Move typedclj.rps-async/Move)

Actual:     (t/HMap :mandatory {:a typedclj.rps-async/Move} :complete? true)
in: {:a :b}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly opt-in to implicit type checking. Change your ns form like so:

```
(ns ^:core.typed typedclj.rps-async
   ...)
```

Comment: Added that, but it makes no difference.

Comment: How are you evaluating things? Are you using an IDE? Lein REPL?

Comment: Thanks, doing more testing in cursive.

Comment: Cool. Looking forward to your next release. Keep up the good work! :-)

Comment: Oh, you can configure (and I did) cursive to use Leiningen nrepl, so I suspect this shouldn't be the real issue here?

Comment: I think Cursive uses some features that I so far don't support. Can you test with the regular `lein repl`? `require`ing the namespace should trigger the type error.

Comment: Try core.typed 0.3.0-alpha2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does report errors at runtime when you explicitly ask it to do so. This is slightly different from statically typed languages, where a type error prevents the program from building successfully – it's just an optional "sanity check" here.

> #### Type checking is separate to compilation and must be explicitly run
>
> Use `clojure.core.typed/check-ns` to type check the current namespace.
>   This can be done at the REPL.
>
> Note: Global annotations like `ann` are only valid when found in a
>   namespace currently being checked with `check-ns`, or wrapped in a `cf`.
>   raw `ann` in a REPL has no effect. Global annotations should be
>   top-level forms or inside a (possibly nested) top-level `do`.
>
> — [`clojure.typed` Quick Guide](https://github.com/clojure/core.typed/wiki/Quick-Guide#type-checking-is-separate-to-compilation-and-must-be-explicitly-run)

In REPL, you should wrap your expressions in `cf`, so that types are inferred from the given code and printed out. (see [this blog post](https://frenchy64.github.io/typed/clojure,/core.typed,/clojure/2013/09/03/core-typed-repl.html)) If you want to type-check code from a namespace defined in source files, use `check-ns` to type-check the entire namespace.

Comment: This was true pre-0.2.92; OP is testing new features.

Comment: @Ambrose is documentation on that **that** hard to find, or it simply does not exist yet?

Comment: There's some docs in the CHANGELOG.md, otherwise none. Feature is still WIP.